# How to convert this specific character to uppercase?

Tags: java, string

i have a string s that i need to iterate through and convert all of the lower case letters to upper case and the upper case letters present to "_"

```
String consonant = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
String upperconsonant = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    String consonantletter = s.substring(i, i + 1);

    if (upperconsonant.toUpperCase().contains(consonantletter) == true) {
        s = s.replace(s.charAt(i), '_');

    } else if (consonant.contains(consonantletter) == true) {
        s=s.replace(s.charAt(i),?????);
    }
}
return s;
```

I'm unsure how to replace the character in question marks, if it is lower case, with the upper case version of its self. I tried converting the character to uppercase, but was getting an error.

Comment: What is your end goal? Could you provide input and expected output and current output?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I guess `s=s.replace(s.charAt(i), Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))` should work

Comment: Do you really want to do this in the same loop? if a letter appears two times, then you would convert the first to uppercase and then replace it later with `_`. So `bB` would end up with `__`.

Comment: The question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the String's char array one by one

```
final String lConsonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
final String uConsonants = lConsonants.toUpperCase();
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    int j = lConsonants.indexOf(chars[i]);
    if (j > -1)
        chars[i] = uConsonants.charAt(j);
    else if (uConsonants.indexOf(chars[i]) > -1)
        chars[i] = '_';
}
s = new String(chars);
```

Comment: The OP wants to convert only consonants. (It is not mentionned in the question but suggested by his/her code.)

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle ahh, nice catch, totally missed that. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: @user5970051 If an answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted, to make it clear that your question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easily by using the following code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String str = "asdfQWERTYzxcv";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[A-Z]","_").toUpperCase());
}
```

Output:

```
ASDF______ZXCV
```

Comment: Reading at the OP's code, it is not exactly what is expected. `str.replaceAll("["+upperconsonant+"]","_")` seems more appropriate.

Comment: *I have a string s that i need to iterate through and convert all of the lower case letters to upper case and the upper case letters present to "_"* Reading this statement and observing that both `consonant` and `upperconsonant` has only different case I assume that OP wants to accomplish this. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The question says *all [...] letters* but the posted code suggests that only consonants should be taken into account. (but I still agree with the regex solution)

Comment: Yes. That got me confused. But even if the Consonants needs to be taken, Regex can be modified. You think that it requires any more changes?